# How to get value type in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to debug and would like to be able to get a function which returns a type of a value.
Is such a thing possible?

I dont wan't :t, I wan't something which can be used in code

such as:

```
[showType i | i <- [0..5] ]
```

returns

```
[Int,Int,Int,Int,Int]
```

Comment: Types and values live in different namespaces.  You can use some reflection to get information, but it's rather limited since all types must be known at compile time anyway.  What are you trying to do with a list of types?

Comment: Another thought: what would the type of `[Int, Int, Int, Int, Int]` be?  You could say that it has _kind_ `[*]`, since `Int` has kind `*`, but I don't think Haskell has kind level lists.

Comment: Since you seem to want this for debugging, note that `GHCi` can tell you with `:t`. Emacs' ghc-mod can also give you the type of an expression.

Comment: … and now I see that you explicitly said you "don't want :t". Sorry :)

Comment: You say you're debugging, but you don't want to use `:t`.  Where in your code would you use the knowledge of something's type to make a decision?  Are you wanting to print out what type it is to the screen?  Are you wanting to do Python-y dynamic typing?  Knowing this information would help gauge what kind of answer this question needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Typeable` class encodes each type uniquely at compile time and can be used for this purpose:

```
import Data.Typeable

showType :: Typeable a => a -> String
showType = show . typeOf
```

with a result of:

```
*Main> showType (+)
"Integer -> Integer -> Integer"
*Main> showType [1..5]
"[Integer]"
*Main> map showType [1..5]
["Integer","Integer","Integer","Integer","Integer"]
```

All this said, Bheklilr is right.  What you actually want might be something different so more details would help us help you.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. It's a bit clumsy sometimes to debug  type errors by only catching them on compile. Id rather get some info this way aswell. It might not be perfect (I did find my bug without this after all) but I wanted to see if it's at least possible.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you rather want something like [`TypedHoles`](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.3/html/users_guide/typed-holes.html). It allows you to write `_` instead of some expression, and the compiler will tell you what type this “hole” has, or should have.

Comment: I think this would be better served as a comment than an answer.